# Export Bigquery Logs

Tags: google-bigquery, stackdriver

I want to analyze the activity on BigQuery during the past month.

I went to the cloud console and the (very inconvenient) log viewer. I set up exports to Big-query, and now I can run queries on the logs and analyze the activity. There is even very convenient guide here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/audit-logs.

However, all this helps to look at data collected from now on. I need to analyze past month.

Is there a way to export existing logs (rather than new) to Bigquery (or to flat file and later load them to BQ)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

While you cannot "backstream" the BigQuery's logs of the past, there is something you can still do, depending on what kind of information you're looking for. If you need information about query jobs (jobs stats, config etc), you can call `Jobs: list` method of BigQuery API to list all jobs in your project. The data is preserved there for 6 months and if you're project owner, you can list the jobs of all users, regardless who actually ran it.

If you don't want to code anything, you can even use [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/bigquery/v2/bigquery.jobs.list) to call the method and save the output as `json` file and then load it back into BigQuery's table.

[image]

[Sample code](https://gist.github.com/Spark2Ignite/8a261c69a5026be66c128a5721266213) to list jobs with BigQuery API. It requires some modification but it should be fairly easy to get it done.

Comment: Using "Jobs:List", how would you extract the User Email, or any other reference to the user that generated the job??

Comment: @N.N. Actually, it's part of the output.

Comment: You can configure it to be part of the output, but it doesn't return (at least not for me)... also, using the API explorer, I get only results spread over many pages. any idea how can I retrieve all data in one call (without manually paginating hundreds of pages)?

Comment: You will need to set "projection" to '''full''' as on my screenshot. Look for the field named something like 'email' (I am away now from my laptop). You can also specify how many results you'd like to get per "page". There is a max of 1000 jobs per page though.

Comment: Thank you. The Projection "full" sorted out the missing email... the complicated part is how to extract it all without writing a script that paginate through all jobs. any idea about that?

Comment: @N.N. - try setting ```maxResults``` to a 10,000. I just tried that and it seems like there is no built-in max. On the other side, I can't really test it because I don't have a project with over 1K jobs. Could you try and provide feedback?

Comment: I have tried with 100K, it cuts it. thank you for your help anyways

Comment: @N.N. - try this [sample code](https://gist.github.com/Spark2Ignite/8a261c69a5026be66c128a5721266213). It requires modification, but it should be fairly easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Jobs: list API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/list) to collect job info and upload it to GBQ
Since it is in GBQ - you can analyze it any way you want using power of BigQuery
You can either flatten result or use original - i recommend using original as it is less headache as no any transformation before loading to GBQ (you just literally upload whatever you got from API). Of course all this in simple app/script that you still have to write

Note: make sure you use `full` value  for `projection` parameter

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping to avoid scripting. I find it really weird that Google cloud guys avoid providing "download" functionality to their logs.

Comment: why i like scripting (at least reasonable amount of it) is because it gives you power of control on what you want, when and how, etc. we are using above apporach for almost two years already and quite happy :o)

Comment: Being a data person, I prefer querying over scripting... I think having data specialists script for paginating trough results, its a waste of their time and skill.

Comment: I think  you missed my point. you use scripting to bring jobs info into bigquery and than you use bigquery to actually query this data and getting whatever insight you are looking for

Comment: at the same time - i do understand that your preference would be to not to deal with scripting at all in such cases. i understand. similar to google analytics being available in bq, i would also expected our jobs logs to be exposed in similar way. so agree!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem when I found a article which describes how to inspect Big Query using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` without any script nor `Jobs: list` as mentioned by other OPs.
I was able to run and got this working.

```
# Monitor Query costs in BigQuery; standard-sql; 2020-06-21
# @see http://www.pascallandau.com/bigquery-snippets/monitor-query-costs/

DECLARE timezone STRING DEFAULT "Europe/Berlin";
DECLARE gb_divisor INT64 DEFAULT 1024*1024*1024;
DECLARE tb_divisor INT64 DEFAULT gb_divisor*1024;
DECLARE cost_per_tb_in_dollar INT64 DEFAULT 5;
DECLARE cost_factor FLOAT64 DEFAULT cost_per_tb_in_dollar / tb_divisor;

SELECT
 DATE(creation_time, timezone) creation_date,
 FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%F %H:%I:%S", creation_time, timezone) as query_time,
 job_id,
 ROUND(total_bytes_processed / gb_divisor,2) as bytes_processed_in_gb,
 IF(cache_hit != true, ROUND(total_bytes_processed * cost_factor,4), 0) as cost_in_dollar,
 project_id,
 user_email,
FROM 
  `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_USER
WHERE
  DATE(creation_time) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) and CURRENT_DATE()
ORDER BY
  bytes_processed_in_gb DESC
```

Credits: https://www.pascallandau.com/bigquery-snippets/monitor-query-costs/